# How can I specify that an object's type is one of several possible object types?

Tags: api, rest, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have an API where I post a set of object to the server, differentiated by type, where each type has some different parameters. The commands are structured like so:

```
{
    "type": <command-name>,
    "args": { 
        <command-specific args>
    }
}
```

For example, these may be two possible commands:

```
{
    "type": "Flooblinate",
    "args": {
        "intensity": "High",
        "frequency": "Every blue moon"
    }
}

{
    "type": "Blagostrate",
    "args": {
        "temperature": 34.5,
        "darkMatter": true
    }
}
```

How can I specify this in Swagger? I can specify an `enum` for `"type"`, but how do I say "`"args"` is one of these possible objects"?

I've checked out [the docs](http://swagger.io/specification/) but nothing stands out. The most promising one was `allOf` because it displayed nicely in the editor ([pastebin](http://pastebin.com/r0UkjZrs), paste into the [online editor](http://editor.swagger.io/)):

```
definitions:
  Product:
    type: object
    allOf:
    - type: object
      title: Flooblinate
      properties:
        intensity:
          type: string
        frequency:
          type: string

    - type: object
      title: Blagostrate
      properties:
        temperature:
          type: number
        darkMatter:
          type: boolean
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

However, this isn't semantically what I need, and, not surprisingly, in the [online viewer](http://petstore.swagger.io/) (that one's not set up for my test case, not sure how to link up a local file easily), they are presented as if all the fields appear at the same time, which is of course what `allOf` means:

[image]

What's the proper way to represent this with Swagger?

Answer (score 1):

According to input from Ron on [the google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swagger-swaggersocket/HN-ABjfebCk), what I want is to use the `discriminator` property:

```
definitions:
  Product:
    type: object
    discriminator: type
    properties:
      type: string
    required: [type]
  Flooblinate:
    allOf:
    - $ref: '#/definitions/Product'
    - type: object
      properties:
        intensity:
          type: string
        frequency:
          type: string
  Blagostrate:
    allOf:
    - $ref: '#/definitions/Product'
    - type: object
      properties:
        temperature:
          type: number
        darkMatter:
          type: boolean
```

Semantically this means what I want it to mean. I should specify `$ref: '#/definitions/Product'` wherever the API accepts or returns any one of `Flooblinate` or `Blagostrate`. Note this requires a field (called `type` here) on the objects to act as the discriminator.

I thought this may be the approach, but the tools didn't show what I expected. However:

> That's because the tools are not 100% in support of the discriminator yet - however, that's the right way to describe your use case.
>   Once you define the discriminator in the top level model, anything that 'allOf's it will be considered a viable option, and indeed you're refer to the top level model for usage.

Comment: The problem I see here is that the discriminator: type would have to match the name of each Product child object. You would need to have Product hold a "type" field where the values are tightly coupled with the name of child objects [Flooblinate, Blagostrate] and if the naming were to ever change, this would break spectacularily. Do you see a way around that?